# how to use distinct in linq for Non-key field

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

how can i get below result with linq?

```
key  salesID  prodname
1    2566     a
2    2566     b
3    3647     c
4    3012     d
```

result

```
  salesID   prodname
    2566     b
    3647     c
    3012     d
```

i want clear all duplicate`salesID`and i use this code but doesn't work

```
  var n = (from p in context.ArefSms where p.Stautos != true select p).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.SalesID).ToList();
```

Comment: Again, saying "doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything about what happened. You've *got* to start giving more information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - we just can't help you at the moment.

Comment: i have all record with this query

Comment: Okay, and so what happened when you used the `GroupBy` approach in my answer? Getting information about this question is like pulling teeth :(

Comment: with your query i have nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to use `GroupBy`:

```
var result = context.MyTable
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Field1)
                    .Select(g => new { Field1 = g.Key,
                                       Field2 = g.First().Field2 });
```

That might give "a" or it might give "b" for the `Field2` value... you haven't made it clear whether or not that's important, or how duplicate values of `Field1` should be handled, basically.

EDIT: So with your real properties, I suspect you want:

```
var query = context.ArefSms
                   .Where(p => !p.Stautos)
                   .GroupBy(p => p.SalesID)
                   .Select(g => new { SalesID = g.Key,
                                      ProdName = g.First().ProdName })
                   .OrderBy(x => x.SalesID);
```

Comment: a or b not that's important and i test your query doesn't work

Comment: @user2304094: "doesn't work" isn't *nearly* enough information. What happens, exactly? You need to give more information if we're going to be able to help you...

Comment: this is my real query (from p in context.ArefSms where p.Stautos != true select p).OrderBy( x => x.SalesID).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: and your query =           var result = context.ArefSms
                    .GroupBy(x => x.SalesID)
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                      
                        Field2 = g.First().ProdName
                    });

Comment: @user2304094: And what happens? Note that you've removed the `where p.Stautos != true` and the `ToList` call. (It's also odd to have that bit of a query expression followed by `OrderBy`, and the comparison with a Boolean constant...)

Comment: when i clear where i have that's problem again i have all record without distnic

Comment: @user2304094: Sorry, your comments really aren't making any sense. Clear what? Please put more effort into being clear - and ideally add more information to the question.